# How to insert text exactly into Gtk::ProgressBar in GTK-3 (Like in GTK-2)

Tags: migration, gtk, progress-bar, gtkmm

I need to add text to progress bar like in this example:

Code was taken completely from official site:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-multithread-example.html.en

But it doesn't work for me. Text "Fraction done" displayed above progress bar, but it should be displayed exactly inside it.
What is the reason? how to fix it ?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJJqs.png] <--- should be like this

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/o00x8.png] <---- looks like this

OS - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method I was shown by a pro.

Use Gtk::Overlay and min-height through the CSS provider.  Example as provided:

```
require 'gtk3'

win = Gtk::Window.new('Sample')
win.signal_connect('destroy') { Gtk.main_quit }

box = Gtk::Box.new(:vertical)

overlay = Gtk::Overlay.new
pb = Gtk::ProgressBar.new
pb.set_fraction(0.5)
# pb.text = ("Something going on. . . ")
# pb.set_show_text(true)
provider = Gtk::CssProvider.new
provider.load(data: <<-CSS)
trough,
progress
{
  min-height: 30px;
}
CSS
pb.style_context.add_provider(provider, Gtk::StyleProvider::PRIORITY_USER)
overlay.add(pb)

label = Gtk::Label.new("Something going on. . . ")
overlay.add_overlay(label)

b = Gtk::Button.new(label: 'Button')
b.signal_connect('clicked') do
  Thread.new do
    5.times do |i|
      sleep 1
      pb.fraction = (i + 1) / 5.0
    end
  end
end

win.add box
box.pack_start overlay
box.pack_start b

win.show_all

Gtk.main
```